# Can legions in Cardfight!! Vanguard be broken/un-legioned?

Tags: cardfight-vanguard

I am new to Cardfight!! Vanguard, and I was wondering if legions be broken or become un-legioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although it can only happen as part of the effect of another card - it's not something you can choose to do when your vanguard is in Legion. For example, [Star-vader, Blaster Joker](http://cardfight.wikia.com/wiki/Star-vader,_Blaster_Joker) can retire one of the opponent's legion mates.

In the case where Legion is broken, the vanguard is no longer considered to be in Legion, and it cannot Legion again. You must ride a new Legion Leader and activate Legion with it.

Comment: if it is unlegioned, can you ride and then legion again (assuming you have 4 cards in the drop zone, and that the legion leaders or mates are not in the damage zone))

Comment: Yes you can. As long as your current vanguard has not legioned this game, it can attempt to legion. Note that your vanguard can only _attempt_ to legion once per game - if it fails (i.e your legion mate is not in the deck), it **cannot** attempt to legion again.